# Can laptop slow down after ram upgrade?

Tags: windows-7, memory, cpu, performance, cpu-usage

I upgraded RAM on my old ThinkPad T400 from 4GB to 8GB.
Is it possible that my laptop slow down because of additional RAM?

It is quite old laptop.
Specs:
Intel Core2Duo P8600 2,4GHz
SSD Samsung Evo 256GB
Originally 2GB RAM, than 2x2GB and now 2x4GB
Win 7 Pro 64-bit

What is happening when I talk about "slow down"? Sometimes it just freezes for some time even when I just browse web. When I look to Windows Task Manager -> Performance Ram is just on maybe 3-4GB used but CPU is at 100% usage. I also think that my laptop is quite hotter then before but it is maybe just false sense or fan is poluted with dust or it is just warm now outside.

Is it possible that now when I finally have enough memory my old CPU isn't able to process so much data?

Thanks for any advance.

Comment: Personally I think this is abnormal. More RAM should never decrease performance.

Comment: @guest It is quite strange but this thought occured to me just because this  - when system needed to store some data in memory to disk, so CPU maybe has enough time to process data because there was less data in memory. But when there is enough memory now, maybe processor can't handle it. But probably it is just bulls**t because processor never handle all data in memory at one time. Maybe clean reinstall of windows will help for some time.

Comment: That does sound illogical to me. ==== For sake of diagnosis, if you revert back to your 2x2GB, would the slowdown be gone? I mean, it could be that the hardware doesn't play well with the 2x4GB, for whatever reason, even though a RAM upgrade in general should not hurt performance.

Answer (score 0):

If the speed of the RAM is slower in the replacement set, then that could also contribute to the issue. RAM is not all about capacity.

edit - although you mention CPU is at 100%, is this during the usual daily tasks? Can you see which process is using the CPU time? It is certainly possible you have found a new bottleneck if the load has increased.

Comment: I usually notice slow down when I browse net. For me browser is great eater of CPU and also RAM.

Comment: I doubt a discrepancy in RAM speed is relevant. A slowdown caused by lower RAM speed would not be accompanied with high CPU usage.

Comment: The two aren't linked, no. 

However, in answer to the question - "Can laptop slow down after ram upgrade?" - if the RAM speed was significantly different (lower) in the new set, then a perceivable difference in system speed may occur. That doesn't seem to be the case here, especially given the laptop base spec has low speed RAM to begin with.

Comment: During the freeze it is CPU-bound, not memory-bound.

Answer (score -1):

The RAM you used might not be compatible with your motherboard. If you cant find appropriate RAM then you can also consider overclocking your processor.

Good Luck.

Comment: I speculated about CPU upgrade (buy faster one) but after that I realised it would be waste of money on such old laptop. Now I think about going back to 4 or maybe 6GB RAM? You mentioned adding unnecessary ram but when I use my laptop I usually see that over 4GB RAM is used so I think it is not unnecessary. What is strange when i got only 4GB ram I haven't problems with RAM, it was usually around maybe 3GB used? I don't know why it is now over 4GB.

Comment: Don't buy new, just overclock your processor (if power and heat isn't your concern) and you'll feel the difference plus your additional RAM won't go to waste after that.

Comment: I concern about heat little bit, I like it when it run so silent and smooth :P Do you think 6GB RAM is good or it is problem that there will be one 4GB ram and one 2GB?

Comment: I read many times that it is recommended to install RAMs in pair (so same capacity and speed) for this reason I asked. I think 6GB will be enough for me. Question is if it run smoother than with 8GB. But I just have to test..

Comment: @Gondil RAM only consume minimal power unlike the pronounced increase in power usage when overclocking CPU.

Comment: @guest I think that same. In that case I'm not going to overclock my CPU :) But thanks for response

Comment: This isn't really an answer to what was asked.